# Recuo após focus em input com jQuery

Tags: jquery

Após o campo receber foco no carregamento da página, o label não é exibido, preciso que, ao receber foco no input, que a página recua um pouco para baixo, para exibir o label.

```
<form role="form" id="formDadosPessoais" onSubmit="return false;">
<div class="col-md-6 lineH">
    <label for="documentoDadosPessoais">CPF/CNPJ:</label>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input autofocus type="text" id="documentoDadosPessoais" name="documentoDadosPessoais" value="<?php echo (isset($cliente_cpfcnpj) ? $cliente_cpfcnpj : ""); ?>" class="form-control" required>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-6 lineH">
    <label for="documento2DadosPessoais">RG/IE/OAB:</label>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" id="documento2DadosPessoais" name="documento2DadosPessoais" value="<?php echo (isset($cliente_rgie) ? $cliente_rgie : ""); ?>" class="form-control">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-12 lineH">
    <label for="nomeDadosPessoais">Nome:</label>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" id="nomeDadosPessoais" name="nomeDadosPessoais" value="<?php echo (isset($cliente_nome) ? $cliente_nome : ""); ?>" class="form-control" required>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-6 lineH">
    <label for="cepDadosPessoais">CEP:</label>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" id="cepDadosPessoais" name="cepDadosPessoais" value="<?php echo (isset($cliente_cep) ? $cliente_cep : ""); ?>" class="form-control" required> <span id="returnCep"></span>
    </div>
</div>
<button id="btnGravarDados" class="btn btn-danger vertical-middle"><i class="fa fa-floppy-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> <strong>GRAVAR REGISTRO</strong></button>
</form>
```

O script:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){

      $("button#btnGravarDados").on('click', function(){

        var documentoDadosPessoais = $("#documentoDadosPessoais").val();
        if(documentoDadosPessoais == "") {
          $('#documentoDadosPessoais').focus();
          window.alert('Preencha o campo em foco');
          return false;
        }

        /* continua validação ...... */

      });

    });
</script>
```

O input recebe o foco, mas o label (CPF/CNPJ) fica acima da janela (escondido), preciso que apareça o label também quando o input recebe foco.

Funcionando em: https://jsfiddle.net/svh46cq2/

Comment: Você poderia detalhar mais esse recuo? Assim a comunidade poderá ajudá-lo mais facilmente.

Comment: Atualizei o código, mas o formulário tem quase 80 inputs, por isso que ao validar e o campo estar não preenchido, ele recebe foco, e o label fica oculto, pois o topo do navegador(janela) tampa, pois o input recebeu foco  mas o label fica pra cima.

Comment: E o problema onde está? aparentemente o focus já faz o que você está querendo fazer. Veja no meu exemplo que fiz https://jsfiddle.net/5vfrqdan/

Comment: Paulo Roberto - Ele recebe foco, mas o label não exibe, pois o foco fica no input, e o label acima, mas o label desaparece pois o topo da janela fica pareado no input com foco.

Comment: Vejam https://jsfiddle.net/svh46cq2/

Ele recebe o foco no input, mas o label (CPF/CNPJ) fica acima da janela (escondido), preciso que apareça o label também quando o input recebe foco.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pelo que entendi você pode usar a função scroolBy e mover alguns pixels acima, pois ele está subindo apenas até o foco do input:

`window.scrollBy(0, -10);`

O Primeiro parametro move o scroll horizontal e o segundo vertical.

Valores positivos movem para baixo e valores negativos movem o scroll para cima, acho que serve para você.

Segue referência: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_scrollby.asp

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente segundo minha necessidade, grato!

Comment: Tranquilo, por nada ;)